# $ORDER vs counting to scan global range

Tags: performance, intersystems-cache

I have a choice between two ways of scanning through a key level in a large global array and am trying to figure out if one method is more efficient than the other.

This is a vendor supplied application and database on the Intersystems Caché database platform. It is written in the old MUMPS style and does not use any of Caché's object persistence functions: all data is stored in globals directly and any indexes are application maintained.

There is a common convention for repeating data elements attached to entities where the first record will contain a count of child records and then each child record is numbered sequentially at the next key level. For example:

```
^GBDATA(12345,100)="3"
^GBDATA(12345,100,1)="A^Record"
^GBDATA(12345,100,2)="B^Record"
^GBDATA(12345,100,3)="C^Record"
```

Where "12345" is the entity key, and "100" is one of the attached detail types. Note that the first "100" record with no other keys has the count of subrecords. There could be anywhere between 0 and hundreds of subrecords attached. The entities are often very wide and there is a lot of other data besides this subrecord type (not shown in example).

Given an entity key, I want to scan through all the subrecords of one type. Would it be faster to use $ORDER to go through the subkeys or to use a FOR loop to anticipate the key values? Does it matter?

$ORDER method:

```
SET EKEY=12345
SET SEQ=""

FOR
{
 SET SEQ=$ORDER(^GBDATA(EKEY,100,SEQ), 1, ROWDATA)
 QUIT:SEQ=""

 WRITE ROWDATA,!
}
```

FOR count method:

```
SET EKEY=12345
SET LIM=^GBDATA(EKEY,100)

FOR SEQ=1:1:LIM
{
 WRITE ^GBDATA(EKEY,100,SEQ),!
}
```

Does anyone know how $ORDER vs $GET is implemented internally in Caché?

I'm having trouble testing this empirically since we only have one production instance with appropriate data and I can't take it offline to clear the cache. I'm most interested in from-disk performance as opposed to from-cache performance.

Comment: If the convention is ever not followed, and there is a gap in the index, or the limit value is lower than the number of items in the list, what should your application do?  Is this more important than speed?  Also, you could pretty easily set up a test with fake data off the production system.

Comment: @psr - The app has been very consistent about this kind of convention in the past, but I'd probably use $GET with a default to hedge against missing values. I have been using $ORDER because it always works and seems like a more direct solution. I could probably test it by setting up a test Caché instance but asking on SO is easier and I wanted to see if anyone knew the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use %SYS.MONLBL to figure out definitively. My guess is that $ORDER is slightly better.

http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCM_monlbl

Comment: Also, psr is right. $ORDER is a more robust solution and better practice.

Comment: Does that give you anything more helpful for this situation than a $ZTIMESTAMP before and after?  If so it would be nice to specifically call it out in your answer.  I guess more precision on the timing is a little bit useful.

Comment: Would the time reported by %SYS.MONLIBL be affected by whether the data being accessed was in the data cache?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your question, "Does anyone know how $ORDER vs $GET is implemented internally in Caché?" The two are completely different functions.
$Order is used for the direction that you're going in when reviewing your ^Global.
$Get is used to pull the data within the ^Global. Below is an example of it's use. I use Cache ObjectScript; however, this should give you a general idea

**Global Structure**

```
^People(LastName,FirstName)="Phone"
```

**Global Data**

```
^People(Doe,John)="1035001234"
^People(Smith,Jane)="7405241305"
^People(Wood,Edgar)="7555127598"
```

**Code Sample**

```
SET LASTNAME=0
FOR QUIT:LASTNAME?." "  DO
.SET LASTNAME=$ORDER(^People(LASTNAME)) QUIT:LASTNAME?." "
.SET FIRSTNAME=0
.FOR QUIT:FIRSTNAME?." "  DO
..SET FIRSTNAME=$ORDER(^People(LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME)) QUIT:FIRSTNAME?." "
..SET PHONE=$GET(^People(LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME))
```

In the sample provided above, it will start with the first record within the ^People global and then start with the first record within the last name by utilizing $Order. It will then $Get the data for the ^People(LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME) node, which is the phone number.

For some samples and reference areas, check out the following links:

[$Get Information](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fget#RCOS_B56034)

[$Order Information](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RVBS_forder#RVBS_B77485)

Comment: That's great but I am aware of what the functions do and how to use them if you had read my code samples in the question. The question was about comparative efficiency, not usage. PS, I see you like the old DO and dot notation for blocks.